# ionic firebase auth worked on web but not ios simulator

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I try to add firebase login in ionic framework.

The chrome web works fine. But when I simulate the app in iOS, the login controller did not be initialized.
I found that the "resolve" did not return the result.
Could any one help me fix the issue? Thanks.

```
      .state('login', {
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
            controller: 'LoginCtrl',
            resolve: {
                // controller will not be loaded until $waitForAuth resolves
                // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
                "currentAuth": ["Auth",
                    function (Auth) {
                        console.log("Got auth result!");

                        // $waitForAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
                        return Auth.$waitForAuth();
                    }]
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an `Auth` factory:

```
app.factory("Auth", function($firebaseAuth) {
    var authRef = new Firebase("yourfirebaseurl.firebaseio.com");
    return $firebaseAuth(authRef);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working in 3 steps:

1. You need to add the inappbrowser plugin `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`
2. add the following 2 lines in config.xml:

`<allow-intent href="*.firebaseio.com" />
<allow-intent href="auth.firebase.com" />`

3. Finally, add this to your index.html:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">`